# Given sum and sum of squares of numbers in an infinite geometric progression, find $y_1$ and $q$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The sum of the numbers in an infinite geometric progression is $8$. Find $y_1$ and $q$ if the sum of the squares of the series numbers is $\frac{512}7$.

This is the way I solved it:

$$S=\frac{y_1}{1-q}\implies y_1=8(1-q)\\
\begin{align}
&S=\frac{y_1^2}{1-q^2}=\frac{64(1-q)^2}{(1-q)(1+q)}=\frac{64(1-q)}{1+q}=\frac{512}7\\
&\implies\frac{1-q}{1+q}=\frac87\\
&\implies7-7q=8+8q\\
&\implies15q=-1\\
&\implies q=-\frac1{15}
\end{align}$$

Is it right?

Comment: That looks correct to me.

Comment: You didn't find $y_1$, though I assume you can. If you're wondering whether it's correct, why not calculate the sum of the series you think it is, and the sum of its squares, and see if they match the numbers in the problem?